# Unresolved attribute reference 'transform' for class 'object'

Tags: python, nltk, chatbot, countvectorizer

I'm having a problem with this CV code. It was working perfectly 4-5 months ago. However, I'm getting an error now: **Unresolved attribute reference 'transform' for class 'object'
**

Does anyone have an idea about how to fix it?

Thank you for your time :)

```
    def wordvector(self,sentence):

        cv=CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda txt: txt.split())
        sentence_words=' '.join(self.clean_up_sentence(sentence))
        words=' '.join(self.words)


        vectorize = cv.fit([words])
        word_vector = vectorize.transform([sentence_words]).toarray().tolist()[0]
        return np.array(word_vector)
```

Comment: You mind posting your entire code and the full traceback?

Comment: What `cv` version were you running then, and what are you running now?